# Minkowski (box-counting) dimension of generalized Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, fractals, dimension-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem.

> For $0<\alpha, \beta<1,$ let $K_{\alpha, \beta}$ be the Cantor set obtained as an intersection of the following nested compact sets. $K_{\alpha, \beta}^{0}=[0,1] .$ The set $K_{\alpha, \beta}^{1}$ is obtained by leaving the first interval of length $\alpha$ and the last interval of length $\beta,$ and removing the interval in between. To get $K_{\alpha, \beta}^{n},$ for each interval $I$ in $K_{\alpha, \beta}^{n-1},$ leave the first interval of length $\alpha|I|$ and the last interval of length $\beta|I|$ and remove the subinterval in between. Compute the Minkowski dimension of $K_{\alpha, \beta}$

---

My attempt.

If assume that $\alpha \le \beta $ then

I believe that after $n$ generations the length of the longest interval $I$ in $K^n_{a,b} $ is $\beta^{n}$ and the length of shortest interval $\alpha^{n}$ and  there are a total of $2^n$ intervals with lengths given by $\alpha^{n-k} \beta^k$ for $k \in \{0, ..., n \}$

But I don't see how to use this information to get the dimension that is $ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{\log{N(K, \varepsilon)}}{\log{\varepsilon^{-1}}} $. I dont know how to find $N(K, \varepsilon)$ the minimal amount of balls with diam = $\varepsilon$ needed to cover $K_{\alpha, \beta}$.
I believe I should find an upper and lower bound for this so that the bounds agree but how to do this?

Comment: Now I think that finding agreeing upper/lower bounds doesn't work here. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I believe for these one-dimensional conformal Iterated Function Systems, the Hausdorff dimension and box-counting dimension agree. You can find this by thermodynamic formalism and Bowen's formula; or an earlier result of Moran. I think the dimension is the solution $s$ to the equation $\alpha^s+\beta^s=1$. More details can be found in G.Iommi's lecture notes http://www.mat.uc.cl/~giommi/notas3_escuela.pdf. (See example 3.5).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks for comment. Yes I think so too, the solution is normally $s$, by Moran's theorem, but from this there can only be numerical solutions (I think). So no nice analytic formula of the from $s=f(\alpha, \beta)$ for some real valued function?